# How do I correct the direction of my vector to the rotation of the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a 3D first person controller game, I am converting a swipe on the screen in a direction vector. 
An object is shot into this direction.
My camera can rotate based on the input of a virtual joystick.
When I don't rotate and shoot the object using swipe it goes in the right direction.
However when I rotate the camera it doesn't go in the intended direction.
The direction should be adapted to the rotation of the camera.

How do I correct the direction of my vector to the rotation of the camera?

PS: Message me for further clarification

```
//Converting swipe direction to 3D direction
public class TouchPair
{
    public Vector2 startPos;
    public int fingerId;
}

private TouchPair touchPair;

void Update()
{
  foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
  {
      Vector2 touchPos = touch.position;

      if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
      {
         Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(touchPos);
         RaycastHit hit;

         if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
         {
            //The player is wielding a bomb that is visible on the screen.
            //only swipes that start from this object should count 
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Bomb")
            {
                touchPair = new TouchPair();
                touchPair.startPos = touchPos;
                touchPair.fingerId = touch.fingerId;
            }
          }
      }
      else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
      {          
         if (touchPair.fingerId == touch.fingerId)
         {
            Vector2 endPos = touchPos;
            Vector2 swipeDirectionRaw = endPos - touchPair.startPos;
            float magnitude = swipeDirectionRaw.magnitude;
            if (magnitude >= minSwipeLength)
            {
                  BombController BombController =                                                           GameObject.FindWithTag("Bomb").GetComponent<BombController>();
                            BombController.Throw(swipeDirectionRaw.normalized, magnitude);
            }
         }
      }
  }
}     

public void Throw(Vector2 direction, float magnitude)
{

    //Setup variables for throw
    throwDirection = new Vector3(direction.x, 0.0f, direction.y);
    throwSpeed = magnitude * throwForce;
}
```

Comment: "I am converting a swipe on the screen in a direction vector." -- Can you show us the code that is doing this? I'm assuming that if you were using [`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) then you wouldn't have an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to get the view vector of the camera. By taking the amount of angles
between the player's forward and the camera's view vector the amount of angles is received that is required to get a correct direction vector.
Finally rotate the shoot direction by this amount of angles.

```
                    Vector2 endPos = touchPos;
                    Vector2 swipeDirectionRaw = endPos - touchPair.startPos;
                    float magnitude = swipeDirectionRaw.magnitude;
                    swipeDirectionRaw.Normalize();
                    if (magnitude >= minSwipeLength)
                    {
                        GameObject player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
                        Vector3 shootOrigin = player.transform.position;
                        Vector3 uncorrectedShootDirection = new Vector3(swipeDirectionRaw.x, 0.0f, swipeDirectionRaw.y);

                        Vector3 originVector = player.transform.forward;
                        Vector3 viewVector = cam.transform.forward;

                        //Shoot direction gets corrected by angle between origin- and view vector
                        float angleBetweenOriginAndView = Vector3.Angle(originVector, viewVector);

                //There is no clockwise or counter-clockwise in 3d space, 
                //hence mirroring is needed. In my case it's done to what suits my needs
                            if (viewVector.x < 0.0f)
                            {
                                angleBetweenOriginAndView *= -1f;
                            }

                        Vector3 correctedShootDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0, angleBetweenOriginAndView, 0) * uncorrectedShootDirection;
                    }

                    touchPair = null;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need raycast with ground when touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended then get direction from your character to raycast.hit.

```
Raycasthit hitInfo;
Physic.Raycast;
```